# Cannot match AES-GCM specification vectors with Java Crypto library

Tags: java, cryptography, aes-gcm

I am trying to use the Java Crypto library as a reference for another application.  To make sure I was getting correct results from the library I ran some sample vectors from the AES-GCM specification to compare the results against the library results.

I am able to get the simplest vector from the specification working, but any of the more complex vectors produce results which do not match the specification.

Test case 1, which passes, uses the following code:

```
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
            GCMParameterSpec parameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(128, stringToByteArray("0", 12));
            SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(stringToByteArray("0", 16), "AES");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, parameterSpec);
            byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal();
```

Test case 2 simply adds 16B of zeros as AAD:

```
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
            GCMParameterSpec parameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(128, stringToByteArray("0", 12));
            SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(stringToByteArray("0", 16), "AES");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, parameterSpec);
            byte[] aad = stringToByteArray("0", 16);
            cipher.updateAAD(aad);
            byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal();
```

This second vector and other more complicated vectors I am unable to get to match.  Can someone familiar with Crypto point out where my reference code is making a mistake?

Full source code available here: [AesGcmSampleVectors on Github](https://github.com/hutch31/AesGcmSampleVectors)

Edit: The Github source code has been updated to reflect the correct output, and has added a passing example of test vector 4 from the GCM
specification.

Comment: Just for completeness please edit your question to include the code for `stringToByteArray`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second test case uses no AAD but a plaintext of 16 0x00 values (you seem to confuse plaintext and AAD):

```
K   00000000000000000000000000000000
P   00000000000000000000000000000000
IV  000000000000000000000000
...
C   0388dace60b6a392f328c2b971b2fe78
T   ab6e47d42cec13bdf53a67b21257bddf
```

Furthermore, it must be taken into account that Java concatenates ciphertext and tag. The following code implements this correctly and is executed successfully:

```java
...
byte[] expected = stringToByteArray("0388dace60b6a392f328c2b971b2fe78ab6e47d42cec13bdf53a67b21257bddf", 32); // Fix 1: Java concatenates ciphertext and Tag
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
GCMParameterSpec parameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(128, stringToByteArray("0", 12));
SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(stringToByteArray("0", 16), "AES");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, parameterSpec);
//byte[] aad = stringToByteArray("0", 12);      // Fix 2: No AAD specified
//cipher.updateAAD(aad);
byte[] plaintext = stringToByteArray("0", 16);  // Fix 3 specified plaintext: 16 0x00 values 
byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plaintext);  

if (Arrays.equals(cipherText, expected)) {
    System.out.println("Vectors compared OK");
} else {
    System.out.println("Vectors compared failed");
    System.out.print("Expected:");
    printByteArray(expected);
    System.out.print("Received:");
    printByteArray(cipherText);
}
...
```

---

AAD are specified e.g. in the fourth test case:

```
K   feffe9928665731c6d6a8f9467308308
P   d9313225f88406e5a55909c5aff5269a86a7a9531534f7da2e4c303d8a318a721c3c0c95956809532fcf0e2449a6b525b16aedf5aa0de657ba637b39
A   feedfacedeadbeeffeedfacedeadbeefabaddad2
IV  cafebabefacedbaddecaf888
...
C   42831ec2217774244b7221b784d0d49ce3aa212f2c02a4e035c17e2329aca12e21d514b25466931c7d8f6a5aac84aa051ba30b396a0aac973d58e091
T   5bc94fbc3221a5db94fae95ae7121a47
```

which is to be implemented as follows (now the `updateAAD()` call is required):

```java
byte[] expected = stringToByteArray("42831ec2217774244b7221b784d0d49ce3aa212f2c02a4e035c17e2329aca12e21d514b25466931c7d8f6a5aac84aa051ba30b396a0aac973d58e0915bc94fbc3221a5db94fae95ae7121a47", 76);
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
GCMParameterSpec parameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(128, stringToByteArray("cafebabefacedbaddecaf888", 12));
SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(stringToByteArray("feffe9928665731c6d6a8f9467308308", 16), "AES");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, parameterSpec);
byte[] aad = stringToByteArray("feedfacedeadbeeffeedfacedeadbeefabaddad2", 20);
cipher.updateAAD(aad);
byte[] plaintext = stringToByteArray("d9313225f88406e5a55909c5aff5269a86a7a9531534f7da2e4c303d8a318a721c3c0c95956809532fcf0e2449a6b525b16aedf5aa0de657ba637b39", 60);
byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plaintext);  

if (Arrays.equals(cipherText, expected)) {
    System.out.println("Vectors compared OK");
} else {
    System.out.println("Vectors compared failed");
    System.out.print("Expected:");
    printByteArray(expected);
    System.out.print("Received:");
    printByteArray(cipherText);
}
```

Comment: Was staring me right in the face.  Thank you!